# Which harmonics will be missing when duty cycle = 30%?

Tags: signal

After some Googling, I found that every n=(1/duty cycle)th harmonics will be missing in the spectrum of a pulse wave. E.g. a 20% duty cycle will have their 5th and 10th harmonics missing.

However, if (1/duty cycle) is not a integer, what kind of spectrum should I expect? I generated a pulse wave of duty cycle = 30% and it seems the 10th harmonics is missing, why is this happening?

Comment: If in doubt, run the equation and see what you get.  Why are you asking us?

Comment: Or just look [here](http://www.engineeringvideos.org/signals-and-systems/fourier-series-example-arbitrary-square-wave). I'm not going to latex al that for you, that's just 20 mins of video, watch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the duty cycle is a rational number

$$D=\frac{p}{q}$$

and \$p\$ and \$q\$ have no common factors, then all harmonics with indices \$n=kq\$ (\$k=1,2,\ldots\$) are zero. So for a duty cycle of \$30\$% \$p=3\$ and \$q=10\$ and all harmonics with indices that are multiples of \$10\$ are zero.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to figure out the harmonic content of a PWM wave is to shift the PWM wave so that the active portion is centered about time=0, superimpose different frequency cosine waves on the PWM wave, and invert (reflect about the Y axis) the portions where the PWM wave is inactive.  Then integrate from -pi to +pi, bearing in mind the fact that the integral of cos(nx) is sin(x)/n, and also bearing in mind the ability to cancel out equal areas above and below the y axis.  Note that centering the PWM wave about time=0 means that the sine terms at every frequency will always be zero, since the positive-time portions will precisely cancel the negative-time portions.

With regard to your particular question, the frequencies which are absent will be those where the areas above and below the y axis cancel perfectly.  Can you see a shortcut to identify such areas?